# Vue - Modifying main.css breaks existing Tailwind class overriding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, tailwind-css

I've been experiencing a strange issue where whenever I change `main.css` in a Vue app, existing Tailwind styles no longer override previous styles. For example, in the following code, `rounded-full` *was* overriding `rounded-md`. `bg-transparent` *was* overriding `bg-white`.

```html
<button class="flex justify-center items-center bg-white text-black rounded-md transition-all ease active:scale-95 rounded-full p-2 w-12 h-12 border-4 text-zinc-100 bg-transparent border-emerald-300">+</button>
```

[A screenshot of how the buttons on the left no longer render as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKjMV.png)

The Vue component that *was* working correctly:

```vue
<script setup>
import { defineEmits, ref, computed } from 'vue'
const emits = defineEmits(['click'])

const props = defineProps({
  text: String,
  disabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  primary: Boolean,
  secondary: Boolean,
  success: Boolean,
  danger: Boolean,
  info: Boolean,
  outline: Boolean,
  toggled: Boolean,
  rounded: Boolean
})

const buttonProps = computed(() => {
  return {
    disabled: props.disabled
  }
})

const buttonStyles = computed(() => {
  const styles = [
    `flex`,
    `justify-center`,
    `items-center`,
    `bg-white`,
    `text-black`,
    `rounded-md`,
    `transition-all`,
    `ease`,
    `active:scale-95`,
  ]

  if (props.rounded) styles.push('rounded-full', 'p-2', 'w-12', 'h-12')
  else styles.push(`py-1`, `px-2`)

  if (props.disabled) {
    styles.push('cursor-not-allowed')
  }

  if (!props.outline || props.toggled) {
    if (props.primary) styles.push('bg-sky-300', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (props.info) styles.push('bg-amber-200', 'text-amber-800')
    if (props.success) styles.push('bg-emerald-300', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (props.danger) styles.push('bg-rose-400', 'text-zinc-100')
  }

  if (props.outline) {
    styles.push('border-4', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (!props.toggled) styles.push('bg-transparent')

    if (props.primary) styles.push('border-sky-300')
    if (props.info) styles.push('border-amber-200', 'text-amber-800')
    if (props.success) styles.push('border-emerald-300')
    if (props.danger) styles.push('border-rose-400')
  }

  return styles
})

const handleClick = () => {
  emits('click')
}
</script>

<template>
  <button
    v-bind="buttonProps"
    :class="buttonStyles"
    @click="handleClick">
    {{ text }}
  </button>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

I have started/restarted `npm` several times including `build` as well. I have checked my `main.css`, and tailwind imports are there. Nothing other than what was supplied is in my `tailwind.config`. Most of my Tailwind code is effectively broken.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should avoid applying multiple classes that change the same property and are of the same variant. This is because the CSS rules that takes precedence when they have the same specificity is the **order of rules in the CSS**, not the HTML.

So to apply this rule to your case, only have one of `rounded-md` or `rounded-full` and one of `bg-transparent` or `bg-white` – not both.

You could modify your code to adhere to this rule like so:

```js
const buttonStyles = computed(() => {
  const styles = [
    `flex`,
    `justify-center`,
    `items-center`,
    `text-black`,
    `transition-all`,
    `ease`,
    `active:scale-95`,
  ]

  if (props.rounded) styles.push('rounded-full', 'p-2', 'w-12', 'h-12')
  else styles.push(`rounded-md`, `py-1`, `px-2`)

  …

  if (!props.outline || props.toggled) {
    if (props.primary) styles.push('bg-sky-300', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (props.info) styles.push('bg-amber-200', 'text-amber-800')
    if (props.success) styles.push('bg-emerald-300', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (props.danger) styles.push('bg-rose-400', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (!(props.primary || props.info || props.success || props.danger)) {
      styles.push('bg-white');
    }
  }

  if (props.outline) {
    styles.push('border-4', 'text-zinc-100')
    if (!props.toggled) styles.push('bg-transparent')
    else {
      styles.push('bg-white')
    }

    …
  } 

  return styles
})
```

You will also want to look at modifying when `text-black` is applied too.

Comment: So, I completely get what you are saying - and I agree. However, my code should work. Overwriting Tailwind classes should take whatever comes last. So even if I have multiple definitions, the last one added should "take effect". I mostly find it odd how it was working originally, yet adding then removing a single, unrelated line of code in `main.css` impacted all of my styles where classes are overridden inline. But, perhaps it's an illusion that it works.

Comment: It is a coincidence that it works. Even if you have multiple definitions, the last one added would not always "take effect". This is because the CSS rules that takes precedence when they have the same specificity is **the order of rules in the CSS**, not the HTML.